# How to create the Quartz Tables for job store in Oracle database?

Tags: spring, oracle, quartz-scheduler, quartz

How to create the Quartz Tables for job store in Oracle database? I am very new to Quartz . If any on has idea how to write the scripts to create, i would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

look for sql scripts which are included in quartz download distribution.

Answer (score 1):

See [this directory](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/tree/d42fb7770f287afbf91f6629d90e7698761ad7d8/quartz-core/src/main/resources/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore) in the Quartz source for the sql to create the Quartz tables. Choose the sql file based on your RDBMS.

Also, for reference, here are some [docs](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/).